# How to style products of a certain category in Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, css, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I want to add unique style to products of a certain category in opencart 2.3.0.2.

Comment: Use same class to define common styles for same category.

Comment: Thanks LIJIN, but where to find them?

Comment: What you need? write a class and put styles to that class. and place the class in html that u want unique style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change style of Particular Category including HTML then first

open

```
catalog/controller/extension/module/category.php
```

At  the end of file you will find line:

```
return $this->load->view('extension/module/category', $data);
```

Here you can add your `if else` condition for particular category ID like:

```
if ($data['category_id'] == 25){
            return $this->load->view('extension/module/categorycustom', $data);
} else {
            return $this->load->view('extension/module/category', $data);
}
```

Add new file at:

catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/categorycustom.tpl

and copy content from

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/category.tpl
```

This will change content of left side filter data.

if you want to change main content at right side then open:

```
catalog/controller/product/category.php
```

Find line around 377

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
```

Add your `if else` condition here to change the main content of the page. Like:

```
if ($category_info['category_id'] == 28){
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/categorynew', $data));
} else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
}
```

Now add new file at:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/categorynew.tpl
```

Copy content from:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl
```

This way you can completely change the layout of particular category page.

Comment: I did! :-) And I my real problem is, I created a category called "coming soon" and I want products of that category to display in front page and in all products page with a flag "Coming soon." How do I proceed?

Comment: first create category, Create Products and assign that category to products. To display in front page check featured products code, you will get idea. For more information share your requirements at vijaymrami@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

In Opencart 2.x, `body` has different classes for every different pages, for example in a category its like: `<body class="product-category-59">`
for another category: `<body class="product-category-70">`

You can use these class for your styles, for example:

```
.product-category-59 a {
    color: red;
}
.product-category-70 a {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mojtaba, this is helpful.